# Good C++ GUI library for FL SDK & VST

Tags: c++, user-interface, vst

What is the best C++ GUI library that can be used in VST and especially in FL SDK (FL Studio SDK). Library that I searching for should not demand a central application object like for example QT does. It must just provide a pure GUI support. I've tested VST GUI, so what else library can I pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out **[Juce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juce)**, it might be helpful.

You can also, check:

**[IPlug](http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=9524)** - An open C++ platform independent framework for VST and AU audio plugins and GUIs &
**[Plugin Developer](http://www.plugindeveloper.com/)** - A resource for VST plugin development, that seems to focus on the IPlug framework.

Comment: Juce is perfect for VST, I've tried it for FL SDK (which is most important target for plugins for me) and it wasn't work right.

Comment: How do the GUI elements of these libraries compare to each other?